# NLTK/NLP buliding a many-to-many/multi-label subject classifier

Tags: python, statistics, nlp, machine-learning, nltk

I have a human tagged corpus of over 5000 subject indexed documents in XML. They vary in size from a few hundred kilobytes to a few hundred megabytes. Being short articles to manuscripts. They have all been subjected indexed as deep as the paragraph level. I am lucky to have such a corpus available, and I am trying to teach myself some NLP concepts. Admittedly, I've only begun. Thus far reading only the freely available NLTK book, [streamhacker](http://streamhacker.com), and skimming jacobs(?) NLTK cookbook. I like to experiment with some ideas.

It was suggested to me, that perhaps, I could take bi-grams and use naive Bayes classification to tag new documents. I feel as if this is the wrong approach. a Naive Bayes is proficient at a true/false sort of relationship, but to use it on my hierarchical tag set I would need to build a new classifier for each tag. Nearly a 1000 of them. I have the memory and processor power to undertake such a task, but am skeptical of the results. However, I will be trying this approach first, to appease someones request. I should likely have this accomplished in the next day or two, but I predict the accuracy to be low.

So my question is a bit open ended. Laregly becuase of the nature of the discipline and the general unfamilirity with my data it will likely be hard to give an exact answer.

1. What sort of classifier would be appropriate for this task. Was I wrong can a Bayes be used for more than a true/false sort of operation.
2. what feature extraction should I pursue for such a task. I am not expecting much with the bigrams.

Each document also contains some citational information including, author/s, an authors gender of m,f,mix(m&f),and other (Gov't inst et al.), document type, published date(16th cent. to current), human analyst, and a few other general elements. I'd also appreciate some useful descriptive tasks to help investigate this data better for gender bias, analyst bias, etc. But realize that is a bit beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: It would be interesting to see if the Normalized Compression Distances between documents in your corpus correlate with the tags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What sort of classifier would be appropriate for this task. Was I wrong can a Bayes be used for more than a true/false sort of operation.

You can easily build a multilabel classifier by [building a separate binary classifier for each class](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/classification-with-more-than-two-classes-1.html#sec:more-than-two-classes), that can distinguish between that class and all others. The classes for which the corresponding classifier yields a positive value are the combined classifier's output. You can use Naïve Bayes for this or any other algorithm. (You could also play tricks with NB's probability output and a threshold value, but NB's probability estimates are notoriously bad; only its ranking among them is what makes it valuable.)

> what feature extraction should I pursue for such a task

For text classification, tf-idf vectors are known to work well, but you haven't specified what the exact task is. Any metadata on the documents might work as well; try doing some simple statistical analysis. If any feature of the data is more frequently present in some classes than in others, it may be a useful feature.

Comment: So, I have no direct task. Sort of putting my feet in the water. What I would like to do is leverage my human tagged corpus to see if I can automate the tagging of a hierarchical ontology at the paragraph level.

Comment: @matchew: then use any features that seem relevant, try out multiple setups and evaluate them. There's no telling what is relevant without seeing the data.

Comment: thank you for the help. Its greatly appreciated. I understand the complexity of the question, but perhaps I should broaden the scope. What types of feature extractions might one pursue. I like the tf-idf much better than bi-grams. But what other ones are often found useful. I understand there is no right answer. 

P.S. I will be leaving this question open for a several more days in hopes to encourage more discussion of my question.

Comment: @matchew: Other options for document features include the output from Latent Dirichlet Allocation or other topic detection models and metadata such as author/title with (maybe learned) weights to boost them relative to the text itself. You may also consider stemming/lemmatizing the text or transforming it to word/POS pairs instead of just words. You can also use several classifiers on several of these spaces, but then you need a way to combine those. (Using an SVM or MaxEnt instead of NB might also increase classifier accuracy.)

Comment: Thank you so much for all the information. I have two last questions. 1. Are you aware of any resources on NLP that provide a well populated mailing list/message board/IRC channel. I anticpate future quesitons, but SO isn't really designed for my open ended questions and long discussions that follow.

2. Is a bit long so I will answer in a follow up response.

Comment: 2. I am pursing the tfidf and MaxEnt/s model. I have ~900 labels. I have created a bag of words for each label. When calculating the tfidf should I consider each BOW(token,labelset) a document N=900. Or should I consider my collection of documents as N. Or should N be number of paragraphs. Each document is labeled per paragraph so each document has a many-to-many relationship with the labels. 

Next, when classifying I should pass a new paragraph with each word have their own tfidf, but then again. How should I conceptualize this to attach the proper tfidf? N=BOWs? N=Documents, N=# of paras?

Comment: @matchew: (1) http://metaoptimize.com/qa is there for your ML questions; NLTK has a mailing list with friendly people on it. (2) If you've labeled per paragraph and you train per paragraph, then you should try to apply your classifier per paragraph. That makes the task harder, though, so you might want to transfer your labels to the document level if it doesn't work.

Comment: So having N/Number of Documents be represented a bunch of uni-grams and label is the wrong option. I need to have it be the document/paragraph. So each label will have multiple tf-idf's for some words? When I calculate the tf-idf for a word I am trying to classify should I then increase N? Thanks for the help. I'm marking this question as answered now.

Comment: @matchew: this is really a new question, something like "how do tf-idf vectors work for classification," that I can hardly answer in the limited space of this comment box.

Comment: I agree. I want to put a little bit of work in on this question. I will likely formulate a new question tonight or tomorrow. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have two tasks to solve here. The 1st one is that you want to tag an article based on its topic(?) and thus the article can be classified in more than one categories/classes and thus you have a multi-label classification problem. There are several algorithms proposed for solving a multi-label classification problem - please check the literature. I found this paper quite helpful when I was dealing with a similar problem: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.104.9401

The 2nd problem you want to solve is to tag the paper with authors, gender, type of document. This is a multi-class problem - each class has more than two potential values but all documents have some values for these classes.

I think as a first step it is important to understand the differences between multi-class and multi-label classification.